# Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in

Tags: php, mysql, linker-errors

I got this warning message when executing my PHP script in Internet webserver, but in local wamp it is working without warnings. what is the reason ?

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/deport/public_html/abc/index.php on line 209
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

mysql_real_escape_string() needs an active connection to the MySQL server and will initiate one with the default data from the php.ini configuration if there is none.

Do not use this function without first connecting to the database.

Also, do not use the mysql_* functions. They are deprecated and will be removed from PHP.

Comment: how to pass the mysql connection handler to this function,and what is the syntax.  Why dont need the connection when used in local WAMP server.

Comment: Have a look at the manual. It is explained there.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a valid connection to your MySQL Server first.

Do `mysql_connect()` before using this function.

Example:

```
$connection = mysql_connect("host","user","pass");
mysql_select_db("dbname",$connection);
echo mysql_real_escape_string("string to be escaped",$connection);
```

You should really use the MySQLi Extension instead of the standard MySQL Extension from PHP.

Comment: how to pass the mysql connection handler to this function,and what is the syntax.  Why dont need the connection when used in local WAMP server.

Comment: Thanks. Why dont need the connection when used in local WAMP server

Comment: Because your MySQL Credentials seem to be in your `php.ini`, so that `mysql_real_escape_string()` could connect automatically to the database.