# PHP code that worked on WAMP localhost but do not work on WebServer

Tags: php, mysql, forms, webserver, localhost

So, I built a website from scracth in PHP and used WAMP server for testing.

Everything is working on localhost, but after uploading the code to the server everything that uses connection to database doesn't work.

I've checked if the POST in php is working on server, and it is working, I changed some `php.ini` configurations after googling and I've done this:

```
register_globals = off; (was default)

allow_url_fopen = on; (was default)

magic_quotes_gpc = off; (was default)
```

**Form Code**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GVNK.png

**The login function inside class**

```
function LoginUser($UserName, $Password)
{
    //Protect from SQL Injection
    $clientusername = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($UserName));
    $clientpassword = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($Password));

    $clientusername = trim($clientusername);
    $clientpassword = trim($clientpassword);

    if($clientusername != "" && $clientusername != "Username" && $clientpassword != "" && $clientpassword != "Password")
    {           
        $this->ConnectToMySQL();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName = '" . $clientusername . "' AND Password = '" . $clientpassword . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->DBConnection, $sql);
        mysqli_close($this->DBConnection);      
        // Mysql_num_row is counting table row      
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
        if($count == 1){
            if(!isset($_SESSION))
                session_start();
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $_SESSION['ID'] = session_id();
            $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
            session_write_close();
            return("O seu login foi feito com sucesso.</br></br><a href='privatemenu.php'>Ir para o Menu</a>");
        }
        else return("Não foram encontrados utilizadores com os dados fornecidos.</br></br><a href='login.php'>Voltar á pagina de Login</a>");

    }
    else return("Ocorreu um erro com a entrada dos seus dados.</br></br><a href='login.php'>Voltar á pagina de Login</a>");
}
```

So, the problem is this, the function always returns the text "Ocorreu um erro com a entrada dos seus dados" in the login function.

I write the login data, push the button Login, the post is working I've tested with the same form and echo the post from the form on another page, but the function never goes trough that first if.

Any help would be very appreciated because I don't think that is from the function, I have another one that only does insert on the database and does exactly the same thing. And whats weird is the data is passing trough the pages correctly.

If anything on this is confuse please ask me so I can explain better.

---

So thanks to Paddyd here is the correct code totally working:

```
function LoginUser($UserName, $Password)
{
    //Protect from SQL Injection
            $this->ConnectToMySQL();
    $clientusername = stripslashes(mysqli_real_escape_string($this->DBConnection, $UserName));
    $clientpassword = stripslashes(mysqli_real_escape_string($this->DBConnection, $Password));

    $clientusername = trim($clientusername);
    $clientpassword = trim($clientpassword);

    if($clientusername != "" && $clientusername != "Username" && $clientpassword != "" && $clientpassword != "Password")
    {           
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName = '" . $clientusername . "' AND Password = '" . $clientpassword . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->DBConnection, $sql);
        mysqli_close($this->DBConnection);      
        // Mysql_num_row is counting table row      
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
        if($count == 1){
            if(!isset($_SESSION))
                session_start();
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $_SESSION['ID'] = session_id();
            $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
            session_write_close();
            return("O seu login foi feito com sucesso.</br></br><a href='privatemenu.php'>Ir para o Menu</a>");
        }
        else return("Não foram encontrados utilizadores com os dados fornecidos.</br></br><a href='login.php'>Voltar á pagina de Login</a>");

    }
    else return("Ocorreu um erro com a entrada dos seus dados.</br></br><a href='login.php'>Voltar á pagina de Login</a>");
}
```

Comment: You should paste the relevant code into your question, rather than include links to it

Comment: Have you modified the credentials for connecting to your database on your server?

Comment: yes the credentials are ok, it was the first thing i tested

Comment: Can you echo `$clientusername` and `$clientpassword` before it reaches the `if` statement inside the `LoginUser` function to see what values they contain

Comment: You should show the connection code,is the host still localhost maybe?

Comment: done the echo, its working, the data is passing correctly

Comment: no, the connection to server is done ok, if it doesnt connect, sends a message with the error.

Comment: So the correct data is being passed through but the if statement still fails?

Comment: yes and the problem is that all similar functions to this all fail

Comment: I just noticed you call `session_start();` in the middle of your code. Usually this should be one of the first lines of code, as it can cause problems with sending headers. Try removing this call, or call it earlier

Comment: done that, still not working, and checked if i have more session_start() on the page, nope, it was the only one

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of your file, see if it outputs any errors

Comment: here it is!!!!
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/httpd/vhosts/jaimevale.com/httpdocs/config/configurations.php on line 461

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/httpd/vhosts/jaimevale.com/httpdocs/config/configurations.php on line 461

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/httpd/vhosts/jaimevale.com/httpdocs/config/configurations.php on line 462

and another one but comments to long

Comment: just tried this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433057/warning-mysql-real-escape-string-function-mysql-real-escape-string-a-link , didnt worked. Anyway, im going to alter all my code and try again, a diferent error poped up, if i resolved it ill post it, thanks a lot Paddyd, its my first time here, is there any thing i can do to mark you helped me?

Comment: Did you try do what i suggested in my answer? No, nothing you can do unless I solved your problem unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/httpd/vhosts/jaimevale.com/httpdocs/config/configurations.php on line 461`

These are the lines causing your problem:

```
$clientusername = stripslashes(mysqli_real_escape_string($UserName));
$clientpassword = stripslashes(mysqli_real_escape_string($Password));
```

You are attempting to use `mysql_real_escape_string` without having established an sql connection.
Either establish a connection before making these calls or use an alternative to `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Try calling `$this->ConnectToMySQL();` at the beginning of your function.

**Edit:** Changed `mysql_real_escape_string` to `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: calling only $this->ConnectToMySQL(); , or calling $this->ConnectToMySQL(); and adding $this->DBConnection, as second argument dont work, the first one gives the same error, the second one:
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in /home/httpd/vhosts/jaimevale.com/httpdocs/config/configurations.php on line 462

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in /home/httpd/vhosts/jaimevale.com/httpdocs/config/configurations.php on line 463

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that you have not set your credentials for the db connection properly

Comment: it is properly connected, the first thing i run on the server was a database script to create tables and insert data, it worked.

Comment: In your `ConnectToMySQL();` function, are you using `mysqli_connect()` or `mysql_connect()`

Comment: im using mysqli_connect(). Maybe its trying to connecting to another place? on the errors show  Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO) , this is not my username on the connection. but the one i do have works..

Comment: Ok try changing `mysql_real_escape_string` to `mysqli_real_escape_string`. See edit in my answer

Comment: so, i changed to msqli, and have the $this->ConnectToMySQL() called first, didnt worked, so i put the $this->DBConnection as second argument. Error now,  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given

Comment: switched the order of the arguments and it worked!!!!! :D thaks a lot Paddyd i dont even know how to thank you!

Comment: Yeah i was just about to say that ;)